# Kafka Consumer Heartbeat Thread Block on Java Nio

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

Software libraries’ Versions in use: Spring 2.2.3.Release, Spring kafka 2.x , Kafka-Client 2.0.0
Java Version: OpenJdk 1.8
Platform Kafka version:  Apache kafka 2.2.0 (https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.1/release-notes.html#apache-kafka-2-2-0-cp2)

Configuration: Topic has 6 partitions.
Data rate: The incoming data rate is 3-4 msgs/second.

Scenario:
With the above configuration a test was run continuously for 3 days. After 2.5 days, I encountered problem in terms of not receiving messages from topic in our consumer group.
Upon detailed investigation, I found out that consumer threads were blocked precisely 18 threads were in blocked state. Also, the thread graph is suggesting that consumer threads were waiting on “Java.nio.

PFA logs and screenshots .
a.) Logs
b.) Screenshots

a)Logs

```
"kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | release-registry-group" #128 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1954001800 nid=0x8a waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f197f7f6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1005)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000000c3382070> (a org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-2-C-1" #127 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f1b6dbc1800 nid=0x89 runnable [0x00007f197f8f6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked <0x00000000c33822d8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
        - locked <0x00000000c33822c8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000c33822e8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:689)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:409)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:510)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:271)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:230)
        - locked <0x00000000c3382070> (a org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:314)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1175)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:732)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:689)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

b.) Screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to understand root cause and possible solutions to fix it and thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the very low volume of messages, is not strange that all threads are blocked waiting for new data to arrive from the network. I have the feeling you are following a red herring, and the issue is somewhere else. Can you enable logging at a lower level? Do you experience the same with newer versions of the libraries?

Comment: Hi @Augusto , thanks for quick response. we are running with replication factor of 2 in kubernetes platform and both of the pods are in block state . so the problem is the consumer group stopped receiving new data after getting into blocked state. Only after we restarted the application, it started consuming messages. Also how to enable lower level logging for kafka? Any pointers on that?